# Endian / Linux firewall question

Tags: linux, firewall, routing

For some reason computers using my endian firewall as the gateway are unable to access any internal machines, when using the external address (setup in Endian Port Forwarding)

For example:

Server with internal address of 192.168.0.210, and external address of 10.0.0.20. When trying to go to 10.0.0.20 on a normal workstation I get a firefox error of:

```
Network Timeout
The server at 10.0.0.20 is taking too long to respond.
```

However I can access the internal address with no problems.

Where and how would I fix this so that my internal machines using the endian IP as the gateway can access local machines with their external addresses with no problems?

All external machines are able to access the external addresses and be routed to their internal addresses with no problems. But ONLY external machines.

Comment: Answered today for a completely different application, but the problem has the same root cause, and therefore the solution is also the same: http://serverfault.com/questions/71734/svn-over-port-3690-failing-over-intranet/71750

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found this motherboard :

Intel LGA 775 Core 2 Quad mini-ITX motherboard with VGA, four PCIe GbE, USB 2.0 and SATA II
 Part Number: KINO-9654G4-R10   SKU Number: 5602

Found here: http://www.orbitmicro.com/global/kino-9654g4-r10-p-5602.html

works VERY well for building your own Endian/Untangle/IPCop/Smoothwall/ANY firewall. It has 4 Gigabit ethernet ports that work great and is very small form factor.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, Endian uses interface-based firewall rules. This means that the rules allowing traffic to the external IPs being applied to whatever NIC you've defined as your "WAN" port. *Somewhere* in the web console I believe there is a setting similar to the effect of "allow inter-zone traffic". Enable that and you should be all set.

Here's a link for the docs for Endian 2.2: http://docs.endian.com/2.2/en/efw.firewall.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem of DNAT you can resolve this in 2 ways:

1) resolve the DNS name of the machine with the internal address

2) do also an SNAT of the source to the internal one but you'll lose the information of the source IP on the server that you're trying to reach